# Instance variables getting reinitialized on device orientation change?

Tags: java, android, oncreate

I am facing an strange issue with using the onSavedInstanceState with only one set of my variables. I am working on a craps game application and I want to save the dice images between orientation changes of the device. The save is successful on first orientation chance (Vertical to Horizontal) but going back from horizontal to vertical (second orientation change) instantly after the first change will reset up my dice images but nothing else. Also if i play the game after first orientation change then its state will be preserved perfectly for the second orientation change.

Through debugging, i figured that the variables carrying the state of my dice (lastDie1 and lastDie2) will get reset (maybe reinitialized) between first and second orientation changes. Their values change from what it used to be (integer referring to a drawable resource) to Zero. I dont know why and I would appreciate any help.

Here are the codes pertaining to different parts of my application.

Declaring variables to save the state of dice.I declared them as fields. They have a class scope.

```
private int lastDie1;
private int lastDie2;
```

here is part of the code that assigns die1 state to the lastDie1 variable. This code is part of a method that simulates the dice roll.

```
switch (di1) {
        case 1:
            die1ImageResource.setImageResource(R.drawable.die1);
            lastDie1 = R.drawable.die1;
            break;
        case 2:
            die1ImageResource.setImageResource(R.drawable.die2);
            lastDie1 = R.drawable.die2;
            break;
        case 3:
            die1ImageResource.setImageResource(R.drawable.die3);
            lastDie1 = R.drawable.die3;
            break;
        case 4:
            die1.setImageResource(R.drawable.die4);
            lastDie1 = R.drawable.die4;
            break;
        case 5:
            die1ImageResource.setImageResource(R.drawable.die5);
            lastDie1 = R.drawable.die5;
            break;
        case 6:
            die1ImageResource.setImageResource(R.drawable.die6);
            lastDie1 = R.drawable.die6;
            break;
        }
```

here is the code for my onSavedInstanceState() method

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        int lDie1 = lastDie1;
        int lDie2 = lastDie2;
        int mPoints = winCount;
        int hPoints = loseCount;
        int resColor = resultsTextView.getCurrentTextColor();
        String reTextView = resultsTextView.getText().toString();
        String pTextView = pointsTextView.getText().toString();
        String roTextView = rollTextView.getText().toString();

        outState.putInt("DIE1_STATE", lDie1);
        outState.putInt("DIE2_STATE", lDie2);
        outState.putInt("MY_POINTS", mPoints);
        outState.putInt("HOUSE_POINTS", hPoints);
        outState.putInt("RESULTS_COLOR", resColor);
        outState.putString("RESULTS", reTextView);
        outState.putString("POINTS", pTextView);
        outState.putString("ROLL", roTextView);

    }
```

here is the part of the code that restores the state on the onCreate method

```
if ( savedInstanceState == null ) // the app just started running
          {
             winCount = 0; 
             loseCount = 0; 
             resultsTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
          } 
          else 
          {

             winCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("MY_POINTS");
             loseCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("HOUSE_POINTS");


             die1.setImageResource(savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE1_STATE"));
             die2.setImageResource(savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE2_STATE"));

             resultsTextView.setTextColor(savedInstanceState.getInt("TEXT_COLOR"));
             resultsTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("RESULTS"));
             pointsTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("POINTS"));
             rollTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("ROLL"));                 

          }
```

As i said everything else's working just fine and their state gets carried over seamlessly but lastDie1 and lastDie2 which appears to get reinitialized while they should not since they are fields like my other variables winCount and loseCount.

Comment: Is your switch statement executed on creation of the activity?  onCreate will be executed again on rotation unless you disable it in the AndroidManifest.  If it is then unless you explicitly check that they were set they will be reinitialized.

Comment: i would advice to store the name of the image rather than storing the image's drawable int value. you can do getDrawables(image name) later to restore state. same applies to Color values also

Comment: Your code to reprocess the `savedInstanceState` assigns to `winCount` and `loseCount`, but I don't see anything that assigns to `lastDie1` or `lastDie2`.

Comment: @RazsApps No the switch is a part of a method that get called upon push of a button. it is not part of  the on create. the push button also is not part of the onCreate either.

Comment: @ajb the value for lastDie1 and lastDie2 get paired with DIE1_STAT and DIE2_STAT at onSavedInstanceState method and then i used the keys at onCreate to restore the image states

Comment: @ajb thanks, i could resolve the issue using your hint. I will post a answer to the question soon

Comment: @Zimex They don't get "paired".  `onSaveInstanceState` uses the value of `lastDie1` for the value named `DIE1_STAT`, because you gave it the value and told it to save it as `DIE1_STAT`.  It doesn't notice, or remember, the name of the variable it got the value from.  Java doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the user ajb @ajb I could resolve the issue and now the app is working the way it should. Here is the solution. the updated code is also posted

from comments

> Your code to reprocess the savedInstanceState assigns to winCount and loseCount, but I don't see anything that assigns to lastDie1 or lastDie2. – ajb
>
> the value for lastDie1 and lastDie2 get paired with DIE1_STAT and DIE2_STAT at onSavedInstanceState method and then i used the keys at onCreate to restore the image states - Zimex
>
> They don't get "paired".  onSaveInstanceState uses the value of lastDie1 for the value named DIE1_STAT, because you gave it the value and told it to save it as DIE1_STAT. It doesn't notice, or remember, the name of the variable it got the value from. Java doesn't work like that. – ajb

```
if ( savedInstanceState == null ) // the app just started running
      {
         winCount = 0; 
         loseCount = 0; 
         resultsTextView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
      } 
      else 
      {

         winCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("MY_POINTS");
         loseCount = savedInstanceState.getInt("HOUSE_POINTS");

         lastDie1 = savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE1_STATE");
         lastDie2 = savedInstanceState.getInt("DIE2_STATE");


         die1ImageView.setImageResource(lastDie1);
         die2ImageView.setImageResource(lastDie2);

         resultsTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("RESULTS"));
         pointsTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("POINTS"));
         rollTextView.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("ROLL"));


      }
```